# django traceback errors manage.py

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am new to Django and followed a tutorial to set up my venv now I am trying to startserver using manage.py I have sqlit3 installed and running when I run the following command

python manage.py startserver

I receive the following error in the picture

```
 File "C:\Users\danyal\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\danyal\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\danyal\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\danyal\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\danyal\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried fixing my settings.py and other cofigs and also reinstalling the python libs but nothing is working please help.

Comment: Did you mean to use `runserver` and not `startserver`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver. Without the actual error message in your question it's not clear what your issue is

Comment: I am unable to load a picture but i put the error in the body